# maven build success. but Target folder not deleted

Tags: java, maven

created new maven project on eclipse. before doing any changes, did a maven clean and it was successful. But target folder didn't get delete. (Tried refreshing, restarting IDE) Should it be deleted after clean success? if yes then what could possibly went wrong?

Comment: What's inside the target folder?

Comment: m2e-wtp>web-resources>META-INF>maven>MANIFEST.MF

Comment: This is automagically generated by the M2E plugin.

Comment: So is it okay to have target folder not being empty even after a successful maven clean?

Comment: It is OK in a sense that it will not hurt, but generally you should investigate what is being locked and why

Comment: Put simply: do not worry about this. It is magic by M2E.

Comment: Did you disable the automatic rebuild in eclipse? Otherwise Eclipse will rebuild right after the clean and therefore create the target folder again.

Comment: @Nitek Just tried disabling auto rebuild and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable the automatic rebuild in eclipse. Otherwise Eclipse will rebuild right after the clean and therefore create the target folder again.

You can disable it unter Project > Build automatically"

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Right after disabling the Auto build in eclipse, did a maven clean and target folder got deleted.